# Control.BeginInvoke - how do I *really* use it for threadsafe UIThread updates in winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, ui-thread, begininvoke

I completely understand the thread logisitics of this question, so I know "what" I want to do but I struggle with C#'s implementation of it.

Here is the scenario: I want to pass an entire control in a thread safe manner to the UIThread for a form to append to a `panel`. This control needs to be generated somehow. Probably using a BeginInvoke. This would be great if I could get some help.

I have a feeling that if I pass a 3rd party class containing the control data that might be enough: here is the thread code:

```
/****
*  scan the UIThread to decide if the frmVerdict needs to be shown, 
*  and if neccesary centre it upon the frmMain if that is also shown
*  either way post an actionable update to frmVerdict or create it
*/
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
frmVerdict form = null;
frmMain parent = null;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
   if (frm is frmVerdict)
   {
      form = (frmVerdict)frm;
   }
   if (frm is frmMain)
   {
      parent = (frmMain)frm;
   }
 }
 if (form == null)
 {
    form = new frmVerdict();
    if (parent != null)
    {
       form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
       form.Location = new Point(parent.Location.X + (parent.Width - form.Width) / 2, parent.Location.Y + (parent.Height - form.Height) / 2);
    }
    form.ShowDialog(); //f.ShowDialog(this)
 }
 form.addAction(action);
 form.BringToFront();
```

inside the form I have this code (among the other things inside `frmVerdict`)

```
public void addAction(classActionType action)
{    
        elementCounter++;
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox(); //TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)Controls["txtbx0001"];
        txtbx.Text = action.thisFileOrFolder.folder.localFolder;
        txtbx.Name = "txtbx" + elementCounter.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
        txtbx.Location = new Point(10, 15 * elementCounter);
        txtbx.Height = 20;
        txtbx.Width = 50;
        pnlVerdict.Controls.Add(txtbx); //this line crashes with Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pnlVerdict' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
        thingsToDo.Add(action);
}
```

the idea was that the thread class would decide if the UIThread had an instance of the `form` frmVerdict and if so post an update to it in the form of a control, or if not just pop the frmVerdict up, this was to be a information response/required set. Then a decision required from the user can be queued. (imagine if a form appears and asks you 1 question then fade "growls" up another question, then it growls a third etc as the thread runs doing work in the background.)

The problem is I get `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pnlVerdict' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` (which is what I would expect). What I need to do is `Control.BeginInvoke` the `(classActionType action)` on the UIThread but **how** do I do that in C#?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you have. You seem to understand the relevant concepts. Just invoke the body of addAction on the UI thread by calling Invoke on *some* control that already lives there.

Comment: yes, I am fairly new to C# how do I physically do the Invokes, I have read around and I understand the "what" but not the "how", also all the examples use simple string sends, which is not as complex

Comment: In addAction, you somehow need to have a reference to any control or form that is running on the UI thread. Maybe just use Application.OpenForms.First(). Then, call Invoke on it.

Comment: You are just doing it wrong.  There's no point to run code that creates a control on a worker thread, it takes a few microseconds at most.  So don't, just BeginInvoke() a method that creates it.  Like your addAction() method.  Only use threads to execute expensive code.

Comment: thanks @HansPassant I changed it on http://pastebin.com/CtKRp639 but now it's a different error on runtime - I think it's lacking a sanity test or two

Comment: You're now invoking on a freshly created control that is not attached to the existing UI thread. Invoke on the existing UI thread.

Comment: that's not true, I am gathering a pointer reference of an open form (or creating it, which may be the sanity test I need to do - for example - how do I instruct it to deliver the frmVerdict into the UIthread) so if the pointer must exist in the UIThread for me to get it then I am in the UIThread when I invoke upon it. I think it's clear I don't know how to tickle C# into doing what it can obviously do. If someone can contribute some code (even via pastebin) that would help.

Comment: it's sub-optimal but I have decided to use this method (borrowing the parent to create the new form) - it seems to work http://pastebin.com/xjvr65yB

Comment: Calling BeginInvoke() *after* the ShowDialog() call cannot work.  The form object is a dead parrot by then, the user closed it.  Focus a bit on writing proper Winforms code before you try to tackle threads.  Plenty of decent books around.

Comment: Using the "parent" is the correct approach because the parent is already a usable control on the right thread. It has its handle created.